# Архитектурное решение: абстракция для похожих классов со статическими методами

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

У меня есть несколько похожих классов, каждый из которых должен уметь сериализовываться и десериализовываться по некоторым правилам, и я не совсем понимаю, как лучше это организовать.

Мне понравилась идея "приватизации" конструктора и создания экземпляров **статическим** методом класса этого класса из строки, например так:

```
var instance = MyClass.CreateFromString(s);
```

Наверное, это какой-то паттерн, но я забыл, как он называется (будет здорово, если кто-то напомнит). Это используется для десериализации.

Сериализация может вызываться просто каким-нибудь перегруженным ToString().

Похожих классов несколько, поэтому хочется закрыть их под какой-нибудь абстракцией (интерфейсом), но в интерфейсы не могут объявлять статические методы класса (в некоторых языках есть инструменты для такой задачи, например, в свифт есть протоколы). С абстракцией проще работать, потом можно создать какую-нибудь "фабрику" или нечто подобное, чтобы передавать в параметры тип и строку, а она мне рождала нужный объект.

Пишу на C#

P.S. Наверное, стоит пояснить, почему хочется закрыть абстракцией: если мне понадобится добавить еще классы такого же вида, то очень хотелось бы всю логику прописать внутри нового класса, ничего больше не исправляя (DRY). При этом желательно иметь какие-то жесткие ограничения (как те, что накладывают интерфейсы), чтобы не было возможности написать такой класс "от балды"

Comment: У `MyClass` все свойства/поля - примитивные типы? Или могут быть сложные?

Comment: В принципе, там только строки. Еще предполагается, что будет BigInteger, так что не только примитивы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Решение](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-virtual-interface-members) нашел. Можно сделать так:

```
public interface IMyClass<T> where T : IMyClass<T>
{
    static abstract T CreateObjectFromString(string s);
}
```

Класс `MyClass`, соответственно, должен реализовывать интерфейс `IMyClass<MyClass>`

Эта возможность называется **Preview Features** и она доступна с версии .NET 5.0, также для ее использования нужно включить в файл `.csproj` проекта `<EnablePreviewFeatures>true</EnablePreviewFeatures>`